# Component names need to start with capital letter?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, api, react-native

So I am trying to use this https://github.com/seeden/react-facebook as part of my hybrid react app. However when I copy and paste the code into my project it gives me an error

```
import React, {Component } from 'react';
import { FacebookProvider, Page } from 'react-facebook';
//import {createBottomTabNavigator, createAppContainer} from 'react- 
navigation';
export default class Home extends Component {
    render(){
       //const { navigate } = this.props.navigation
    return (
       <FacebookProvider appId="2319566588264121">
           <Page href="https://www.facebook.com/somepage/" tabs="timeline" 
            />
       </FacebookProvider> 
    );
   }
 }
```

The idea is to have a facebooks pages feed show up on my app screen. However [I get this error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/62eZf.png):

```
Invariant Violation: View config not found for name div. Make sure to start component names with a capital letter.

This error is located at:
  in div (created by Page)
  in Page (created by Parser)
  in Initialize (created by Context.Consumer)
  in ForwardRef (created by Parser)
  in div (created by Parser)
  in Parser (created by ForwardRef)
  in ForwardRef (at Home.js:18)
  in Facebook (at Home.js:17)
  in Home (at SceneView.js:0)
  in SceneView (at createTabNavigator.js139)
  in RCTView (at View.js:45)
  in View (at ResourceSavingScene.js:37)
  in RCTView (at View.js:45)
  in View (at ResourceSavingScene.js:26)
  in ResourceSavingScene (at createllottomTabNavigatorls:121)
  in RCTView (at View.js:45)
  in View (at screens.native.js:83)
  in ScreenContainer (at create00ttomTabNavigator.js:111)
  in RCTView (at View.js:46)
  in View (at createBottomTabNavigator.js: 110)
  in TabNavigationView (at createTabNavigator.js:197)
  in NavigationView (at createNavigator.js:61)
  in Navigator (at createAppContainer.js:429)
  in NavigationContainer (at . .
```

Comment: Include the text of the error, not a screenshot.  Search engines won't index based on the error in the image.

Comment: Maybe there is something wrong with your configuration. Have you tried https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app. It creates you a new project with an example page. It's just one command and everything should be generated and configured correctly.

Answer (score 5):

It looks like [seeden/react-facebook](https://github.com/seeden/react-facebook) is built for browsers and the DOM. You cannot use `<div>` and the likes in React Native -- This means you have to implement this library yourself, or find something else that is React Native compatible

Answer (score 0):

Yes,components' names must start with capital letter , because , when you write component name with small letter , compiler runs it like as html tag, but when you write with capital letter , compiler runs it from your javascript file location.